# react native: how to know a component is sticky when use stickyHeaderIndices in scrollView

Tags: react-native

In react native: I use stickyHeaderIndices in scrollView to make a header fixed on top when scroll up. How I can know if the header is sticky or not? Like I would like to change style or do some state change when the header is sticky or not sticky.